# Internet Explorer reloads IFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-11, zk

I've got a web form (using the  ZK framework), let's say at **http://www.example.com/myform**

This form get's included in my main page (for example **http://www.anotherexample.com**) in an iframe.

Now the strange thing:

In Internet Explorer 9-11, the IFrame completely reloads whenever I unfocus a field (some field checking happens there). But this ONLY happens in IE and ONLY in the IFrame. If I load the **http://www.example.com/myform** directly, it works fine.

Another detail that makes the whole thing strange is: If I addtionally open a tab in the IE and load **http://www.example.com/myform** there, the iframe suddenly also works fine (after one reload).

Unfortunately, IE does not display any errors when reloading the iframe, so I have no clue what happens and why. Other browsers (Firefox, Chrome) work perfectly fine with the IFrame.

Any clues what might be the reason there?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the reason was P3P, as described here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2013/09/17/a-quick-look-at-p3p/

In short, Internet Explorer rejects cookies from third-party contexts (different domain) in iframes, etc. This of course leads to the behavior mentioned:

- Any request (including something that triggers on "focus lost") sent to the ZK backend will not have a session id (because no cookie), so ZK will trigger a complete reload.
- Opening the ZK application in another tab allows it to create a cookie - which then the ZK application inside the iframe can access

The solution is to send the correct P3P header, in ZK this can be done in various ways, for example via the [.zul file header directive](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/ZUML/Processing_Instructions/header), in a servlet filter or directly on the webserver. Having done this, the application works as expected in IE 9-11.